# Problems expanding a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I'm trying to expand the function f(x). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

I started off with this function:
$$
f(x) = {z^3 \over (z-{1 \over 4})(z-{3 \over 4})(z-{1 \over 2})}
$$

And then said that it equals:

$$
{A \over (z-{1 \over 4})}+
{B \over (z-{3 \over 4})}+
{C \over (z-{1 \over 2})}
$$

I then calculated A, B and C by doing:

$$
A(z-{3 \over 4})(z-{1 \over 2})+
B(z-{1 \over 4})(z-{1 \over 2})+
C(z-{1 \over 4})(z-{3 \over 4})=z^3
$$

$$
= A(z^2-{5 \over 4}z + {3 \over 8})+
B(z^2-{3 \over 4}z + {1 \over 8})+
C(z^2-z + {3 \over 16})
$$

I then expanded that to the following [equation system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%2Bb%2Bc%3D0+and+-5%2F4a-3%2F4b-c%3D0+and+3%2F8a%2B1%2F8b%2B3%2F16c%3D0), which according to Wolfram has the solutions $a = 0,   b = 0, c = 0$. This is the solution that I was hoping to get

$$
{{1 \over 2} \over{1 - {1\over 4}z^{-1}}}+
{{9 \over 2} \over{1 - {3\over 4}z^{-1}}}+
{4 \over{1 - {1\over 2}z^{-1}}}
$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original problem was to get from $$ f(x) = {1 \over (1-{1 \over 4}z^{-1})(1-{3 \over 4}z^{-1})(1-{1 \over 2}z^{-1})} $$ to $$
{{1 \over 2} \over{1 - {1\over 4}z^{-1}}}+
{{9 \over 2} \over{1 - {3\over 4}z^{-1}}}+
{4 \over{1 - {1\over 2}z^{-1}}}
$$
I don't think you can do this by multiplying top and bottom by $z^3$. Instead, you want to introduce some symbol to stand for $z^{-1}$; let's let $y=z^{-1}$. Then by the usual partial fractions technique, we set up $${1 \over (1-{1 \over 4}y)(1-{3 \over 4}y)(1-{1 \over 2}y)}={A\over1-(1/4)y}+{B\over1-(3/4)y}+{C\over1-(1/2)y} $$ Clearing fractions, $$1=A(1-(3/4)y)(1-(1/2)y)+B(1-(1/4)y)(1-(1/2)y)+C(1-(1/4)y)(1-(3/4)y)$$ Let $y=4/3$ to get $B=9/2$. Let $y=2$ to get $C=-4$. Let $y=4$ to get $A=1/2$, and you're done (only notice I'm getting $C=-4$, not $C=4$).

Answer (score 1):

This partial fraction decomposition only works if the terms on the bottom are all linear, i.e. of the form $a + bz$. Clearly $1 - \frac{1}{4}z^{-1}$ is not of the form, nor are any of the others.

To remedy this, need to get the function in terms of positive powers of $z$. We therefore multiply the top and bottom by $z^3$ to get
$$f(z) = \frac{z^3}{(z - \frac{1}{4})(z - \frac{3}{4})(z - \frac{1}{2})}$$
Now we can use polynomial long division, followed by partial fractions, to get $f(z)$ in a form we can integrate.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I still haven't gotten the hang of it, so I updated the question with your changes. I suspect that it's the equation system that is wrong. Would you mind taking another look at it? Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I realize that I'm supposed to do polynomial long division now, but I don't see how I will get the "expected" answer by doing that. Won't I get an answer in the form $1 + 1/xyz$ instead of $1/xyz$?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the expected answer is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's right under "This is the solution that I was hoping to get"

Comment: But that doesn't have $z$ in it at all --- that's just a number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, sorry! Fixed it now.

Comment: 1. I think you're missing a plus sign between the 2nd and 3rd fractions. 2. Where did all those $z^{-1}$ terms come from? I think you may have made a mistake when you edited your question to get rid of the $z^{-1}$ terms in the original --- you won't get them in the answer if they aren't there to start with.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can get them if you remove $z^3 \over z^3$ from f(x). Otherwise you can just multiply the expected answer with $z^3 \over z^3$. It means the same thing. I did forget a plus-sign though.

Comment: You cannot get from $(1/2)/((1/4)-z^{-1})$ to $A/(z-(1/4))$ by multiplying by $z^3/z^3$ or by any other form of the number 1.